# Change locale from outside any component (not using useSetLocale hook)

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm migrating my react-admin app to v3.

It uses a custom redux-saga effect (`USER_CHECK_SUCCESS`) to call the `changeLocale` method but that's not supported anymore : https://marmelab.com/blog/2019/10/10/react-admin-v3-i18n.html

Problem is, I don't know how to re-implement it, I can't use the `useSetLocale` hook since I'm not running inside of a react component.

```
import {
    USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    USER_CHECK,
    USER_CHECK_SUCCESS,
    changeLocale
} from "react-admin";

import {takeEvery, put} from "redux-saga/effects";

export default function* authSagas() {
    // takeEvery deprecated ? removed ? https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/releases/tag/v1.0.0
    yield takeEvery(USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, handleLanguage);
    yield takeEvery(USER_CHECK, handleLanguage);
    yield takeEvery(USER_CHECK_SUCCESS, handleLanguage);
}

export function* handleLanguage(action) {
    if(!localStorage.getItem('authenticated')){
        return;
    }
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authenticated'));
    if(user.locale){
        // Should try/catch ? https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/releases/tag/v1.0.0
        yield put(changeLocale(user.locale));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried making a wrapper component or a context?

Comment: That's where I need guidance I guess

Comment: Try to solve it first and tell us where your error is before asking us to do it for you.